# Xamarin.Forms: Picker doesn't work as expected on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, focus, picker

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms app** on which I try to fix a **strange behavior on Android** about a `Picker`.

On a screen, there is a `Picker` allowing to select a **department**: after the selection of the department, a list of items is updated.

The first time this screen is displayed, the `Picker` is "focused" automatically, so the user has just to select the department: the items list is well updated.

If the user wants to change the department, he has to click on the `Picker`.

But in these case, there are **2 behaviors** on Android:

- on **Android 10/11**, all works fine: the items are refresh after the department change
- on **Android 8**, the items are not refreshed: this is probably because the `Unfocused` event is called as soon as the user click on the `Picker`.

***I don't understand why we encounter 2 different behaviors...***

Here are the main files:

The base `BorderlessPicker`:

```
public class BorderlessPicker : Picker
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsBorderlessPickerFocusProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsBorderlessPickerFocus),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(BorderlessPicker),
            false,
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: IsBorderlessPickerFocusPropertyChanged);

    public bool IsBorderlessPickerFocus
    {
        get => (bool)this.GetValue(IsBorderlessPickerFocusProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(IsBorderlessPickerFocusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void IsBorderlessPickerFocusPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var borderlessPicker = bindable as BorderlessPicker;
        if (borderlessPicker != null && (newValue as bool?) == true)
        {
            borderlessPicker.Focus();
        }
    }

    public BorderlessPicker()
    {
        this.Unfocused += BorderlessPicker_Unfocused;
    }

    private void BorderlessPicker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        // REMARK: Setting IsBorderlessPickerFocus property to notify the related viewmodel about this event
        this.IsBorderlessPickerFocus = false;
    }
```

The control `DepartmentPickerControl`:

```
public partial class DepartmentPickerControl : ShadowFrame
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainLabelTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MainLabelText), typeof(string), typeof(DepartmentPickerControl), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string MainLabelText
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(MainLabelTextProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(MainLabelTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSubLabelVisibleProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsSubLabelVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(DepartmentPickerControl), true, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public bool IsSubLabelVisible
    {
        get => (bool)this.GetValue(IsSubLabelVisibleProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(IsSubLabelVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    public DepartmentPickerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Department_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.depPicker.IsBorderlessPickerFocus = true;
    }
}
```

The `XAML` of this control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:ShadowFrame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                ...
                x:Name="This"
                HasShadow="true"
                CornerRadius="2"
                HeightRequest="44"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                Padding="16,8">
    
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource GrayCardInfoHeader}"
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=MainLabelText}" />
        
        <my:BorderlessPicker x:Name="depPicker"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource RedCardInfoPicker}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding FullName}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartement}"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            IsVisible="false"
                            BackgroundColor="Lime"
                            Title="{prs:Strings common.department_picker.title}"
                            IsBorderlessPickerFocus="{Binding IsDepPickerFocus}" />
        
        <Label x:Name="Test2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource RedCardInfoLabel}"
            Text="{Binding DisplayedDepartment}"
            IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=IsSubLabelVisible}" />

        <my:FontIconLabel Grid.Column="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource RedCardInfoLabel}"
                        Text="&#x0059;" />
        
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Department_Tapped" />
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    </Grid>
</my:ShadowFrame>
```

This control is used in the **main page** like this:

```
<ctrl:DepartmentPickerControl IsSubLabelVisible="false" MainLabelText="{Binding DisplayedDepartment}" />

<ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          SelectionMode="None"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

And the **main ViewModel** looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemsViewModel> items;

private bool isNationalItemsSelected;
private bool isDepartmentalItemsSelected;
private bool areDepartmentalItemsVisible;

private ObservableCollection<DepartmentViewModel> departments;
private DepartmentViewModel selectedDepartment;
private string displayedDepartment;
private bool isDepPickerFocus;

public ObservableCollection<ItemsViewModel> Items
{
    get => this.items;
    set => this.Set(ref this.items, value);
}

public ObservableCollection<DepartmentViewModel> Departments
{
    get => this.departments;
    set => this.Set(ref this.departments, value);
}

public DepartmentViewModel SelectedDepartement
{
    get => this.selectedDepartment;
    set
    {
        this.Set(ref this.selectedDepartment, value);
        if (value != null)
        {
            this.DisplayedDepartment = value.FullName;
        }
    }
}

public string DisplayedDepartment
{
    get => this.displayedDepartment;
    set => this.Set(ref this.displayedDepartment, value);
}

public bool IsDepPickerFocus
{
    get => this.isDepPickerFocus;
    set
    {
        if (this.isDepPickerFocus == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Set(ref this.isDepPickerFocus, value);
        if (!this.isDepPickerFocus && selectedDepartment != null)
        {
            DisplayDepartmentalItems();
        }
    }
}

private void DisplayDepartmentalItems()
{
    this.IsNationalItemsSelected = false;
    this.IsDepartmentalItemsSelected = true;

    this.Items = this.departmentalItems
        .Where(ds => ds.DepartmentCode == this.selectedDepartment.Code)
        .ToObservable();
}

public RelayCommand FocusDepartmentPickerCommand => new RelayCommand(this.FocusDepartmentPicker);

private void FocusDepartmentPicker()
{
    if (this.isDepartmentalItemselected) return;

    if (this.SelectedDepartement == null)
    {
        this.IsDepPickerFocus = true;
        return;
    }
    
    this.SelectedDepartement = this.departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Code == departmentCode);
    this.DisplayedDepartment = this.selectedDepartment.FullName;
    
    DisplayDepartmentalItems();
}
```

***Would you have any explanation?
What is also strange is that when I put some breakpoints, all works well on Android 8...***

**Update**:

This has been fixed by adding a `Task.Delay` on `Department_Tapped`:

```
private async void Department_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(75);
    this.depPicker.IsBorderlessPickerFocus = true;
}
```

***This is not really perfect, but I didn't found a better approach...***

Comment: You might consider adding the following code when the data changes：this.forceUpdate(), or you might consider using Picker-View.

Comment: But there is already a `Picker` view as `BorderlessPicker` inherits from `Picker`.
The problem is that the `BorderlessPicker_Unfocused` is called as soon as user click on the `Picker` on old Android devices: this is not the case on other Android devices or on iOS...

Comment: Then what about the Android 9 platform, you may have a try.